# Query to account for Rolling DB

Tags: sql, powershell

**Issue:**  Microsoft SQL 2016
Every quarter my application creates a new archive DB to store data. Every quarter I manually run my queries against the prior quarter archive DB to gather data for analytic purposes.

I have a PowerShell script that runs my queries, however, I still have to update my PowerShell automation to specify the archive DB I want to run the query off.

**Example:**

```
ArchiveDB_Q1_2016
ArchiveDB_Q1_2017
ArchiveDB_Q2_2016
ArchiveDB_Q2_2017
ArchiveDB_Q3_2016
ArchiveDB_Q3_2017
ArchiveDB_Q4_2016
ArchiveDB_Q4_2017
```

Today being 10/9/17 I want to run my query for the ArchiveDB_Q3_2017.

In My PowerShell I am specifying the DB I want to query (`$dbName = 'ArchiveDB_Q3_2017'`).

January 2nd 2018, I want to run my queries for ArchiveDB_Q4_2017. Currently, I have to open my PowerShell script, update the DB name, save, then execute the script.

I want to be able to automate these queries, so that regardless of what quarter we are in, I am always running my query off the prior quarter archive DB.

How do I accomplish this?

Is there a command or string I can use in PowerShell to account for the DB name changes, or would it be easier to create a text doc with a SQL query that looks at the previous quarter archive DB, and then use PowerShell to pull in the results from that query to pass into the DB parameter in my PowerShell script for the use in the rest of the queries?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL - Version 2016

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the current quarter with an integer division:

```
$today   = (Get-Date).Date
$current = [Math]::Floor(($today.Month - 1) / 3) + 1
```

The previous quarter is `$current - 1`, with one exception: for the first quarter the previous quarter is 4 and the year is the current year minus one.

```
$prev = $current - 1
$year = $today.Year
if ($prev -eq 0) {
    $prev = 4
    $year = $year - 1
}
```

With these 2 values you can simply construct the database name like this:

```
$dbName = "ArchiveDB_Q${prev}_${year}"
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked exactly as I needed. Minor Modification but awesome! 

$dbName = “Moxy_Q$($prev)_$($year)”

Comment: `$($prev)` shouldn't do anything different from `${prev}` here.